# Get width of an element after the browser has determined its width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a pop up box that I want to be perfectly centered on the window. It has the following CSS properties:

```
#pop_up {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid green;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 5px white;
    width: -webkit-max-content;
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: max-content;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

I also have some jQuery stuff that sets this element's `left` and `top` properties.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window_height = $(window).height();
    window_width = $(window).width();
    pop_up_height = $('#pop_up').outerHeight();
    pop_up_width = $('#pop_up').outerWidth();
    pop_up_left = (window_width / 2) - (pop_up_width / 2);
    pop_up_top = (window_height / 2) - (pop_up_height / 2);
    $('#pop_up').css('left', pop_up_left);
    $('#pop_up').css('top', pop_up_top);
});
```

I had it alert me of all of the variables and the window variables were right but for `pop_up_height` and `pop_up_width` it would alert me `'4'`. This obviously means that it is only getting the border. If I change it to `.innerHeight();` and `.innerWidth();` it alerts `'0'`. So, it is returning the width before the browser decides according to my `width: max-content;` property. Trying to figure how to get the width after the browser `auto`'s it.

Also, when I specify a `left` property does it position the element according to the border or to the actual inside of the element? So if I gave an element 2px border and a left of 20px, would the border be 20px from the left or the actual inside of the element? Just a side question.

Comment: The easiest way to center any element is: `#selector {margin: auto; left: 0; right: 0; position: absolute;}`. Is this what you're after?

Answer (score 2):

```
function popCenter()
{
  $('#pop_up').css({'top':($(window).height()-$('#pop_up').height())/2,'left':($(window).width()-$('#pop_up').width())/2});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 popCenter();
 })

$(window).resize(function() { //if resize the window, keep the selector in center;
 popCenter(); 
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

No the border will not be 20 px.
And the element will stick to left .

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$("#pop_up").width();` and .height()

Comment: Returned '0'. Wonder if it has something to do with my funky 'max-content' property value...

Comment: Who are you addressing?